# Yiddish: "װאָס הערט זיך?" — "Vos hert zikh?" — What is the German origin?

Tags: dialect, yiddish

What is the German origin of the Yiddish oh-so-common expression

> װאָס הערט זיך?

Which means "How are you?"

If you cannot read Hebrew, the Yiddish expression is [pronounced](https://he.wikivoyage.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%97%D7%95%D7%9F_%D7%99%D7%99%D7%93%D7%99#%D7%9E%D7%91%D7%97%D7%A8_%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D,_%D7%91%D7%99%D7%98%D7%95%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A4%D7%98%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%91%D7%99%D7%99%D7%93%D7%99%D7%A9) more-or-less as `Vos hert zikh?`, depending on the Yiddish dialect.

Comment: https://jel.jewish-languages.org/words/330 claims that the literal translation was _What is heard?_. So it makes sense to assume that the root german phrase was _Was hört sich?_ Diese Redewendung existiert im Standarddeutschen nicht. Aber natürlich kann es gut sein, dass es einen Dialekt gibt oder gab, in dem das die Anrede war.

Comment: Very good, I think you are right on the money... I did not realize that that was the literal meaning. I have asked several native speakers of German but they could not guess what was the German origin.

Comment: Actually, that was what I would have thought on first glance anyway, just trusting the phonetics. But it might be a bit hard to guess, since the phrase does not exist in contemporary standard german and is even ungrammatic: _hören_ is not reflexive and _sich_ is clearly the reflexive pronoun here.

Comment: lol. I just realized I unconsciously switched from english to german in the first comment. Second part of the comment is: This phrase does not exist in standard german. But it is very possible, that there is or was a dialect where this was a salutaional formula.

Comment: *Man sieht sich.* – *Man hört sich.* are standard German, but they are saluations for leaving or hanging up the phone.

Comment: @Janka Ah, ya, true. I didn't think of _man hört sich_, where _sich_ is not a reflexive but a personal pronoun.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach also compare *Das hört sich gut für mich an*, "That sounds good to me".

Comment: Compare further *Da hört sich alles auf*, not in my repertoire but somewhat close to "enough is enough, that's where the buck stops" (where "buck" might compare to *Bogen*, *den Bogen überspannen*). Given *wir hören uns*, I don't quite understand your distinction between personal pronoun and reflexivity, @jonathan.scholbach although aptly, PIE \*swe- is categorized as pronoun. *Und damit hat sich's!* "basta!" (ellipsis of a perfect formation? cp. *Es hat sich zugetragen* etc.), or *sich haben* (*hab dich nicht so* "don't be like that").

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Das wird kommen von

> Was hört sich?

gleichbedeutend mit "Was hört man?", oder wie man heute sagen würde:

> Na, was gibt's Neues?

Die im Deutschen eigentlich "falsche" reflexive Verwendung von *hören* (*hört sich*) lässt sich leicht erklären durch Sprachkontakt mit dem Slavischen. Die Mehrzahl der jiddisch Sprechenden lebten ja einst in Galizien/Polen/Ukraine/etc. also in einer Gegend, wo viel slavisch gesprochen wird. In den slavischen Sprachen sind reflexive Verben häufiger im Einsatz als im Deutschen.<sup>1</sup> Im Bulgarischen etwa (bloß weil ich das am besten kann) kann man sagen:

> Какво се чува? = "Was-sich-hört?"

oder eben: Was ist zu hören?

Im Polnischen, Weißrussischen, Russischen, Ukrainischen etc. ist das ähnlich.

Wer in Gegenden mit mehreren Verkehrssprachen lebt, vermischt gerne einmal den Wortschatz, aber auch grammatische Strukturen. Das passiert sogar mir ab und zu: Wenn ich eine Weile lang nur Bulgarisch geredet habe, fange ich an, im Deutschen Verben reflexiv zu verwenden, die man nach den Gepflogenheiten der Standardsprache nicht reflexiv verwenden kann. Es ist aber oft praktisch, da kürzer. (Beispiele folgen, sobald mir welche einfallen.)

---

<sup>1)</sup> Viele Verben, die bei uns nicht reflexiv sind, sind in slavischen Sprachen reflexiv. Bulgarisch *разхождам се* für *ich gehe spazieren* ist wörtlich: "ich-spazierengehe sich" oder noch präziser: "ich-rumlaufen sich".

Comment: Sehr interessant! Das ist genau das Wissen, das mit gefehlt hat :-) +1, auch weil du klar machst, wo Wissen und Spekulation getrennt sind.

Comment: zur Fußnote: wie auch *sich die Beine vertreten*, oder frz. *se promener*. Oder vielleicht vergleichbar: *Was tut sich?*, was man so zwar nicht sagt, aber denkbar wäre.

Comment: @Philipp  Wenn wir schon am Sammeln eigenartiger Reflexivverwendungen von Verben sind: - *Hat sich was mit Spazierengehen. Es ist Regen angesagt." - "Das nimmt sich nix. Spielen wir halt Schach." Keine Ahnung, wo diese Wendungen herkommen. Freche These: am Ende aus dem Jiddischen?

Comment: Danke vielmals!